# Best location for system-wide bash aliases to be managed by CM tools?

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I understand that, normally, system-wide aliases (which affect all users) belong in `/etc/bash.bashrc` (at least on Arch Linux and other common distros I'm familiar with).

However, for automatically managing system-wide configuration on multiple devices, it would be much easier (especially for removal) if our custom aliases are stored in one or more known (and dedicated) files which are sourced by `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Unfortunately, `/etc/bash.bashrc` does not automatically source files from a standard directory. But `/etc/profile` does.

Therefore, I am contemplating putting our custom aliases into files like `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`. My other option would be to add code to `/etc/bash.bashrc` to source our custom files, but that seems to be the less favorable option.

Are there other better options? What should I be aware of if I do source aliases (and similar system-wide settings) from `/etc/profile.d/`?

In case it is not clear, the issue I want to address is to avoid having a script make changes to `/etc/bash.bashrc` upon adding or removing aliases and similar custom settings. The configuration management (as well as system admin) will be much simpler if the adding and removing is limited to whole files, such as our known `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` files. What is the best way to proceed?